# nested independant iterators over shuffled array

Tags: java, arrays, random, iterator

I have implemented an iterable randomized queue using a resizing array in java. The problem comes when I try to have two independent iterators over the same data in different random order. The main creates a queue of 5 integers (0-4) and then a nested while loop to iterate over the data in independent random orders. The inner loop works fine through each iteration (i.e. prints out 0-4 in 5 different random orders). The problem is that when the inner iterator is created, it overwrites the data in the first iterator, except for the index variable i. So calling next() on the outer iterator returns the value at its index in the inner iterator.

Examples:
If the inner iterator returns 1 3 2 0 4 after the 1st time through. The call to next() on the outer iterator will return 1.
If the inner iterator returns 3 0 4 2 1 after the 3rd time through. The call to next() on the outer iterator will return 4.
If the inner iterator returns 4 1 0 3 2 after the 5th time through. The call to next() on the outer iterator will return 2.

How do I make it so the iterators are independent of each other?

```
...
// return an independent iterator over items in random order
public Iterator<Item> iterator() {
    if (N == 0) return null;
    return new RandomizedQueueIterator();
}

private class RandomizedQueueIterator implements Iterator<Item> {
    private int i;
    private Item[] array;
    public RandomizedQueueIterator() {
        array = a;
        StdRandom.shuffle(array, 0, N-1);
        i = 0;
    }
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return i < N;
    }
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Remove not supported");
    }
    public Item next() {
        if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException("No more items");
        return array[i++];
    }
}
...
// unit testing
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RandomizedQueue rq = new RandomizedQueue();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        rq.enqueue(i);
    Iterator iterator = rq.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Iterator innerIt = rq.iterator();
        while (innerIt.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(innerIt.next() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
}
```

The shuffle method works fine implementing the Knuth Shuffle algorithm.

Comment: Did you try instantiaing the innerIt out side both loops?

Comment: the problem is with the iterator itself, not the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to make a copy of your array in the iterator constructor. 
See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T[],%20int)

```
    array = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
```